# How to suppress StyleCop rule SA1515 in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin, stylecop, visual-studio-mac

In a Xamarin project in Visual Studio for Mac I am trying to configure StyleCop.

I have successfully suppressed rule SA1512 SingleLineCommentsMustNotBeFollowedByBlankLine in Settings.StyleCop.

I use

```
<Rule Name="SingleLineCommentsMustNotBeFollowedByBlankLine">
  <RuleSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
  </RuleSettings>
</Rule>
```

When I try to suppress SA1515 SingleLineCommentsMustBePrecededByBlankLine with this

```
<Rule Name="SingleLineCommentsMustBePrecededByBlankLine">
  <RuleSettings>
    <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
  </RuleSettings>
</Rule>
```

it does not work. The only documentation on the rule names I have been able to find is [this](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com)

Am I using the wrong rule name? Does there exist any other documentation on the rule names or any other way to go from the warning about rule SA1515 to suppressing it project-wide?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2017.
Changing the rule name to `SingleLineCommentMustBePrecededByBlankLine` finally disabled the rule.